# Opencv how to get image stream from Mat quickly?

Tags: c++, opencv

I can use imwrite() to write the image(like "face.jpg") into disk,
then use fstream to read this jpg into a array.this array is what I want.

but,how to get this quickly? from memmory not disk.
I thought the image data in Mat.data,length is Mat.cols*Mat.rows.I was not sure it is or not right.so,I used fstream write it into disk,then opened it with image viewer,nothing.there must something wrong.

```
Mat frame; 
VideoCapture cap(0); 
if (!cap.isOpened())
{ 
   return -1; 
} 
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 160); 
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120); 
cap >> frame; 
if(frame.empty()){
   return -2;
}
//I just want the pointer and length of image information,the following is just for testing
//whether that the same as I thought,if it's right ,frame.data and len is what I want,but it not work.
FILE *fp = fopen("face.jpg", "wb"); 
if (NULL==fp) 
{
   return -1; 
} 
int len = frame.cols*frame.rows; //or 3*frame.cols*frame.rows
fwrite(frame.data, len, sizeof(char), fp); 
fclose(fp);


namedWindow("face", 1);
imshow("face", frame);
waitKey(1000);
```

I'm new in opencv,and I just want get the image data.thanks for help!

Comment: May be you want `imencode()` http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imencode

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? you want to copy raw bytes from image to another structure?

Comment: Note that frame.cols*frame.rows is true only when image is continous. There can be padding added at end of each row, say if width is 477, not a multiple of 16. I dont remember if it was 16 or 32, but some power of 2 is used for padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this just with imencode(),thanks for @ZdaR.

```
    vector<uchar> buff;
    vector<int>param = vector<int>(2);
    param[0] = CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY;
    param[1] = 95;
    imencode(".jpg", frame, buff, param);
    int len = buff.size();
    FILE *fout;
    fout = fopen("555.jpg", "wb");
    if(NULL==fout){
         return -3;
    }
    fwrite(&buff[0], 1, len*sizeof(uchar), fout);
    fclose(fout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the dimensions before you write it to disk? It'll be helpful for the others to see your code here. In the case of Mat, unless your data is grayscale, the size will be more than cols * rows. You should verify if the format is RGB, RGBA, or YUV, etc. In the case of JPEG, it'll be most likely RGBX; so you should really check that your stream size is either 3 * cols * rows or 4 * cols * rows.

Comment: thanks for help,I have uploaded my code .the frame.step is 480(160,3),I have checked 3*cols*rows,not work.if there need a header?

Comment: You could try to do an imshow of the frame prior to file writing? Just to verify the data is there. And is the Video stream from a webcam? You should probably stream it longer.

Comment: of course,the video stream came from my Logitech C310,imshow is below this code,and work pefect.everything fine but what I want.

Comment: If I've not mistaken. Using imwrite and FILE are two different things. With imwrite you have the JPEG header and this tells the image viewer how to interpret the data. With FILE you have just raw bytes, common image viewers would not understand how to translate this data. Is this what you were doing?

Comment: yes.another problem is with FILE the face.jpg always 57KB,but the same frame with imwrite  the value is 3~10KB,if make a header,the face.jpg size can't become smaller.so,I don't think this will sovle the problem,but I will try.

Comment: No. I don't think placing a header will solve your problem. The size difference is due to compression. So in JPEG data there are more to it than just header. You should probably write out as bitmap.

Comment: it maybe work,someone told me to use cbitmap.I'm looking for covert Mat to bitmap.If you have any suggestion? Thanks a lot.